# Set Focus in VisualStatemanager

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

I write a custom control and want to set the focus on a control in case a VisualState goes active.

The control is a kind of ComboBox with a search box in the drop down popup. When I open it, the `Opened` Visual State goes active and the search box should be focused. Besides a dependency property `bool IsDropDownOpen` will be `true`.

PS: It's an Windows 10 UWP project.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but you can set focus only programmatically, not by visual state :(

Comment: That's annoying. Do you know if it's possible to create a custom animation in UWP? I can derive from `TimeLine` or `ObjectKeyFrame`  but there is nothing to animate a value like `GetCurrentValue` in WPF.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't try WPF never... 
What do you want animate?

Comment: In WPF you can create a custom animation. So you can set the focus to a given control at a certain time. But I do not know if it is possible in UWP too.

Comment: @Koopakiller, no, you can't create custom animation in UWP. All about animation in UWP you can find [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/graphics/animations-overview?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 1):

Not my favorite solution, but a workaround without accessing the `TextBox` from code behind.

I implemented an attached property which sets the focus to a control in case the property is set to `true`.

```
public class FocusHelper : DependencyObject
{
    #region Attached Properties

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsFocusedProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsFocused", typeof(bool), typeof(FocusHelper), new PropertyMetadata(default(bool), OnIsFocusedChanged));

    public static bool GetIsFocused(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsFocusedProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsFocused(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsFocusedProperty, value);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

    public static void OnIsFocusedChanged(DependencyObject s, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var ctrl = s as Control;
        if (ctrl == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException();
        }

        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            ctrl.Focus(FocusState.Keyboard);
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

So I can bind this property to my `IsDropDownOpen` property. So every time I open the drop down, the `TextBox` will get the focus.

```
<TextBox helper:FocusHelper.IsFocused="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=OneWay}" ...
```